# i cant access inbuilt mysql database that contains all users and their privileges

Tags: mysql, azure, cleardb

i created a mySQL database using clearDB thats running on microsoft azure. i've been trying to change my user privileges for quite sometime but i keep getting the same error that i have no permission to access the mysql.user table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, SUPER privileges are **not** available to customers on ClearDB shared-resource systems.
If you want add additional users or other request, you can open a Support ticket or email support@cleardb.com, [they](https://getsatisfaction.com/cleardb/topics/multiple-users-in-mysql-pro-60) will create them for you.

Comment: i tried to switch to another mysql server but i also have trouble creating triggers they say i dont have permission. i read several sources online, they say i can only change my user privileges only if am logged in as 'root'. but how do i login as 'root' on a remote mysql server, am always getting access denied error when i try to do this.